# Can't see console message outside of the constructor, why?

Tags: nestjs

I am learning nestjs. I appreciate hearing any comments.

At the moment, I am testing whether the data I call from MongoDB works as I expected or not. Before that, I am trying to make the constructor aware of the async variable, getMissionStatus().

I am trying to see the message 'idx(1)' on my debug console. But I cannot understand why I cannot see the log message. However, I can obviously see the console log message when I do so within the constructor. If I am out to use the console.log, then it stopped. So I added this.getMissionStatus(); in the constructor and now it is not working.

What else can I try to see the console message? I feel like I am missing something.
Note: this file is service.ts in nestjs.

```
// MissionEntryTimeCount.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class MissionEntryTimeCount {
    constructor(@Inject('CONNECTOR') private readonly Missions: Model<any>) {
        this.getMissionStatus();
    }
    async getMissionStatus(): Promise<any> {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        // mongoose
        const missions = await this.Missions.find({}).exec();
        const missionStatus = [];

        // for iteration - to compare:
        for (const mission of missions) {
            const selectedAt = mission.selectedAt;
            const closedAt = mission.closedAt;

            const status = {
                missionId: mission._idx,
                isSelected: false,
                isClosed: false,
            };
            if (selectedAt && currentTime >= selectedAt) {
                status.isSelected = true;
            }
            if (closedAt && currentTime >= closedAt) {
                status.isClosed = true;
            }

            if (currentTime.getTime() > 2) {
                console.log('idx(1)');
            }
            if (closedAt && closedAt.getTime() < currentTime.getTime()) {
                console.log('idx(2)');
            }
            missionStatus.push(status);
        }
        return missionStatus;
    }
```

Comment: First, does your mongoose request works ? If you do `console.log(missions)` after your find what happens ? Do you reach the console.log ? And if yes, is there something in the array ?
And second, it's not a good idea to do an async call in a constructor, because the constructor can't "await" your function. If you want to do an async call at the startup of your service you should use onModuleInit() as shown here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I made it by following the document you linked. Thanks.